# How do I create a desktop shortcut with Python (Ubuntu)?

Tags: python, ubuntu, shortcut-file

I was wondering how do I create a shortcut file on the desktop in Ubuntu (or any Linux Distro) with Python. I am specifically interested in modifying the Target Path string.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [pyxdg](http://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pyxdg) may be useful.

Comment: This is much more related to the targeted [Desktop Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Desktop_environment) than Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [*.desktop file](http://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/latest/) and put it in the desktop folder. See also [how to add it to the Unity launcher](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UnityLaunchersAndDesktopFiles).

Comment: This worked! Just having a problem setting the file to executable. Would you mind helping me with that?